# App crashes during startup with valueForUndefinedKey error

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios5

During the app startup, I show a table view. Each row shows a managed object's data in some form. One customer is reporting a crash in the app startup. I looked at his crash log and could track down to a place where I use `[NSManagedObject valueForKey:]` method inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The app crashes with `[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:]` exception.

How come just one device in a 1000s of devices could get this issue? Running the same version of iOS and the app, I couldn't imitate it in any of my devices. what could have gone wrong?

```
Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x3549e88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x368c5259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3549e5c5 -[NSException init] + 1
3   CoreData                        0x329d3b23 -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 327
4   Foundation                      0x312b59d1 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 125
5   CoreData                        0x3298d995 -[NSManagedObject valueForKey:] + 121
6   MyApp                   0x0000c513 -[Activity isOn:] (Activity.m:371)
7   MyApp                   0x0000beaf -[Activity firstMarkableDate] (Activity.m:163)
8   MyApp                   0x0000c0cb -[Activity statusString] (Activity.m:220)
9   MyApp                   0x0000bd51 -[Activity statusColor] (Activity.m:139)
10  MyApp                   0x00004af1 -[ActivityListViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (ActivityListViewController.m:418)
11  UIKit                           0x3251d0a3 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 547
```

Comment: Did you, at any point, update your app? In other words, could it be a version change in your core-data model?

Comment: app's core data schema was not changed at all in any of the udpates. And the same app version runs perfectly on every one of our devices (non-development devices)

Comment: You must look at your `Activity`, it seems that it doesn't have `-isOn:` implemented (note the colon).

Comment: it is implemented and it works on all of our devices. line 371 in [Activity isOn:] inside Activity.m access a managed object property using [object valueForKey:"trackname"] line

Comment: What valueForKey are you calling, what should the value be, where is the key/value set and how/what is it set to.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a memory management issue. See `-[Activity isOn:]` where it invokes `valueForKey:`. The object you send `valueForKey:` is apparently of the wrong class. See where the object is coming from.

The object may get over-released and its memory address may get occupied by an object of a different class which isn't KVO-compliant for `trackname` key. If that's the case, I would bet that your app gets `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` even more often.

Why would that happen? `NSManagedObjects` have many subtleties with regard to their lifetime. They may get deleted in other parts of your app, for example, so you should always expect that and act appropriately.

I hope this will point you in the right direction.